# jMeter - Paramater from JSR223 PreProcesser is not replacing the parameter in JSON request body in the request

Tags: jmeter, json

mobileNubmer is being generated in JSR223 PreProcessor but it's not replacing the parameter in the request body (JSON). Here is my setup and what am I doing wrong?

```
JSR223 PreProcessor
def randomValue = ${__Random(00000000,99999999)} as String 
def mobileNumber = "04" + randomValue
vars.put('randomValue', mobileNumber)
```

Follow by HTTP request

```
HTTP request
POST - Body
{
    "senderId": "Test",
    "messages": [
    {"to": ${mobileNumber}}]
 }
```

Failed request

```
POST https://api

POST data:
{
    "senderId": "SMAPIJ",
    "messages": [
    {"to": ${mobileNumber}}]
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

All good. I wasn't using the right parameter. I replaced mobileNumber with randomValue and it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

As per [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) documentation:

> The JSR223 test elements have a feature (compilation) that can significantly increase performance. To benefit from this feature:
>
> - Use Script files instead of inlining them. This will make JMeter compile them if this feature is available on ScriptEngine and cache them.
> - Or Use Script Text and check Cache compiled script if available property.
>
> When using this feature, ensure your script code **does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code as caching would only cache first replacement.** Instead use script parameters.

So either call [__Random() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) directly in your HTTP Request body like:

```
{
  "senderId": "SMAPIJ",
  "messages": [
    {
      "to": 04${__Random(00000000,99999999)}
    }
  ]
}
```

or if you prefer to generate a random number in Groovy amend your code to look like:

```
def randomValue = '04' + String.format('%07d', org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(0, 99999999))
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)